# How to use sed to append multiple lines to a file?

Tags: sed

Yes I searched the site and I don't think I seen anything to specifically addressed my very (simple I imagine) issue that I just cannot overcome.

I'm taking a Linux class and I have been asked this question:

> Use the sed command and a script file to add these lines to the end of the `CD_list` file:
>
> ```
> hard rock:1008:70
> misc:1009:22
> ```

I have tried over and over, and read the chapter. I can't figure this out.

The file CD_list is created, and I need to append those two above lines to it as shown using a script file. Yup stumped.

Comment: sed ? why not use a simple append `>>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible answer:
<strike>`sed -i 's/^$/hard rock:1008:70\nmisc:1009:22/' CD_list`</strike>

**EDIT:** try this instead
`sed -i '$ a\hard rock:1008:70\nmisc:1009:22' CD_list`

I think it's the **a** command you're after.

Here is a fantastic resource:
http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: That looks like it would replace all empty lines, not append two lines at the end.

Comment: You're right...blank out...I should look over those resources myself!

Comment: That also appends a spurious `/`.

Comment: According to [the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html), "Each embedded <newline> in the text shall be preceded by a <backslash>. Other <backslash> characters in text shall be removed, and the following character shall be treated literally." So using `\n` to mean "newline" seems to be non-portable.

Comment: I appreciate you helping, and showing me a different way of doing this :)

Answer (score 4):

Put the following in `script.sed`:

```
$a \
hard rock:1008:70\
misc:1009:22
```

Then run `sed -f script.sed CD_list`. This will output `CD_list` and the appended lines to standard out. If you want to modify the file in place, use `sed -i -f script.sed CD_list`.

---

Here's how it works: We use `$` to match the last line of the file. Then we run the `a` (append) command, which outputs the text coming after it at the end of the current cycle. Normally a newline would terminate the `a` command, so we use `\` (backslash) to escape the newline and output it as-is.

(Information taken from https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-Programs.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Seeing it now makes it look overly simplistic thanks for the linked resource :)